# Prolog - programming a board game called Adugo

Tags: matrix, prolog

In the past few days I have tried doing the game [Adugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adugo) in a prolog program, but Logic programming is a bit hard for me. I'm trying do it simple as possible, the initial matrix is :

```
        [[1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
         [1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
         [1,1,2,0,0,0,0],
         [1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
         [1,1,1,0,0,0,0]]).
```

- 1 is for the dogs
- 2 is the jaguar
- 0 is nothing

The user will only control the dogs and the jaguar will be a bot.I have done this game in C++, but in Prolog I don't know how to do.

Comment: The matrix representation seems too simple for the game. Look at [ugraph](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ugraphs) instead.

Comment: I don't see why too make so sophisticated, but I will look more about ugraph.

Answer (score 1):

The game is quite fun. I have not yet completed the development,
but the basic idea is to use a predicate [set_arg/4](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/blog/en/docs/05_run/02_reference/structure/univ.html) to change the board
state. A predicate arg/3 is already found in the ISO core standard, it simply picks an argument from a compound. If it were not already predefined one could bootstrap via univ (=..)/2 as follows:

```
arg(K, C, A) :-
    C =.. [_|L],
    nth1(K, L, A).
```

Now the predicate set_arg/3 works similarly but its aim is not to access an argument, but instead to modify an argument. But since in Prolog terms are immutable, we simply return a new modified term and thus retain declarativity. It can be bootstrapped as follows:

```
set_arg(K, C, A, D) :-
    C =.. [F|L],
    nth1(K, L, _, H),
    nth1(K, R, A, H),
    D =.. [F|R].
```

Prolog implementors will not like such a bootstrapping, the univ (=..)/2 is notoriously a predicate that slows down the Prolog interpreter. In Jekejeke Prolog we have native support for a built-in set_arg/4 which makes it less a burden for the Prolog interpreter.

With set_arg/4 we can then implement the Adugo game moves relatively simple. Here is an example move, when a Jaguar (*) eats a Dog (o) by jumping over it. The link predicate represents the board topology including "streets":

```
move(S, K, *, T, K-I) :-
   link(K, J, M),
   arg(J, S, o),
   N is M+1,
   link(J, I, N),
   arg(I, S, +),
   set_arg(J, S, +, H),
   set_arg(K, H, +, L),
   set_arg(I, L, *, T).
```

Here is a screenshot of the midst of our [game development](https://gist.github.com/jburse/67d6e69352a1ceacba910d54dc0c4996#file-adugo-p). A game session can be started by the predicate game/2. The game/2 predicate cannot yet correctly detect an end of a game. But we are working on it:

[image]

Efficiency is not so bad. Since the Prolog interpreter allows just in time multi-argument indexing the move search via the link/3 topology database is quite fast. Other areas could be maybe improved, like a counter for the dogs and some alpha/beta pruning.